# Azure CLI very slow for stopping VMs from bash

Tags: bash, azure, virtual-machine, azure-cli

I have the following bash script to stop all VMs:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

servers=(Server1 Server2 Server3)

#stop all vws
for s in "${servers[@]}"; do
    az vm stop --resource-group RG1 --name ${s}
done

echo "all wm are stopped..."
```

This script doesn't terminate in a reasonable time. Is there a way to speed this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script itself is doing very little; `az` is doing all the work, but it's likely you can run them all in parallel:

```
for s in "${servers[@]}"; do
  az vm stop --resource-group RG1 --name "$s" &
done

wait

echo "all wm are stopped..."
```